# Using Custom button for Google Translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make this bootstrap Translate button work as if it was the google translate button? https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/1hx1b5sr/

So that when the translate button I created opens the menu from the google button when its pressed. Maybe hiding but using the functionality somehow?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-border-bottom navbar-right">
    <li class="">

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="search fa fa-language"></i> Translate
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="google_translate_element" style="float:left; padding-left:15px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear..

Comment: Where is the Bootstrap button? I don't see it in your code or fiddle, just a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the Google Translate button with `opacity: 0`. Opacity does not remove the button, so it is still possible to click it, even if it is not visible. You need to place your own button behind the invisible Google Translate button, otherwise it wouldn't be clickable (it is covered). Be aware that `:hover` and `:focus` and so on do not work on the visible button, because it is covered by the invisible one. The `position: relative;` on the parent is necessary, because `position` always orients on the next parent which has also the attribute `position` set to something other than `static`.

Replace this line:

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="float:left; padding-left:15px"></div>
```

With these lines

```
<div style="position: relative;">
   <div id="google_translate_element" style="position: relative; opacity: 0;"></div>
   <button style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1;">Translate</button>
</div>
```